# Disappointing results with OpenMP

Tags: opencv, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize some code using OpenCV and OpenMP.

The code is performing FFT's on 100 images, independently. This is performed in a parallel for loop that calls the function where FFT is computed.

As there are no data dependencies, I would expect the speedup to be proportional to the number of cores (4 real, 8 logical).

But the sequential version takes 2 seconds, while the parallelized one a poor 1.2 seconds. I do observe the workload increasing on the cores, nearly reaching 100% total processor load (vs. about 20% in the single-thread case), but this does not translate to faster execution.

Below, the execution times for an increasing number of threads:

```
1: 2092 ms
2: 1348 ms
3: 1199 ms
4: 1173 ms
5: 1183 ms
6: 1200 ms
7: 1205 ms
8: 1167 ms
9: 1182 ms
10: 1174 ms
```

Could this be due to the overhead of OpenMP, or am I missing something ?

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you run the code in parallel and serial and the number of the cores?

Comment: I have tried a single for loop (same for serial and parallel). I have also tried a double loop, the outer parallelized over 8 iterations and the inner one performing 100/8 FFTs sequentially. There are 8 logical cores.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The FFT algorithm implemented in OpenCV could already be parallelized internally.

Comment: @Catree: I don't think so. when I increase the number of threads used for parallelization, the total workload increases strongly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You can look into the source code. From this [file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/e1f5b886fbc864174fb9266def5c20f58eef5ae3/modules/core/src/dxt.cpp#L1552), it looks like the algo is parallelized and uses Intel IPP. If you have 8 threads, you can try to use [setNumThreads()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gae78625c3c2aa9e0b83ed31b73c6549c0) to use only 4 threads for OpenCV and do the same in OpenMP to use only 2 threads.

Comment: @Catree: mh, I don't confirm that a parallellized version is used. Changing the number of threads via setNumThreads has no effect on the running-time.

Comment: if you do not use OpenMP, what's the processor load?

Comment: @Micka: consistently between 18% and 24%, as if there were just 4 cores (and not 8 logical ones).

Comment: Judging by your tests I would suggest you try to run a parallel version of FFT, it is likely that your memory controller is saturated so running more than 2 in parallel won't help much.